# my S3 requests keep adding up, even when I dont have any s3 buckets?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, cloud-hosting

I have been monitoring my billing dashboard for a few days now and I notice that my s3 requests, put, copy, post, list requests and get requests keep adding up even though Im not using s3, in fact I have stopped using my AWS account for few days to monitor any changes, also I have deleted all my previously created s3 buckets, lambda functions associated with it, dynamodb tables, api gateways. I remeber hosting  a website using s3, but I had deleted that bucket, is there something that i am missing which is causing it. I am on the free tier and I am afraid that I might exceed the free tier if I dont know what is causing this, despite mine not using my AWS account. i am new to AWS hence, the difficulty in understanding it. I would really appreciate some help in this matter.

Comment: The free tier includes 20,000 GET requests per month. Requests beyond that cost `$0.0004 per 1000 requests`. So, don't panic for the moment. How many requests are listed?

Comment: hey, yes but I still need to know why the requests are being made, for my better understanding of how aws works,  even when I am not using it, probably there is some service still running, idk.

Comment: **How many requests are being listed?** It is possible that the requests are coming from your use of the console (eg listing S3 buckets, even if they don't exist), or possibly other services that refer to S3.